# How do I use imagemagick to emulate lens color aberration?

Tags: image, imagemagick

Suppose I have a camera image called source.png and I want to split the channels, affine expand each channel by a different coefficient, and recombine into target.png without creating intermediate files?

I am trying things like this:

> convert source.png -colorspace RGB -separate {expansions} -combine target.png

I experimented for many hours trying to take hints from the imagemagick site
and from other sources on the web, but I did not get it working.

Can anyone show me a simple example of independent channel processing?

Mark Setchell gave me enough foundation to experiment and SUCCEED!
ANSWER:

```
convert Home.png -write MPR:orig +delete \
  \( MPR:orig -separate -delete 1,2 -affine -1.00,0,0,-1.00,0,0 -transform -gravity Center -extent 180x180 \) \
  \( MPR:orig -separate -delete 0,2 -affine -1.06,0,0,-1.06,0,0 -transform -gravity Center -extent 180x180 \) \
  \( MPR:orig -separate -delete 0,1 -affine -1.31,0,0,-1.31,0,0 -transform -gravity Center -extent 180x180 \) \
  -combine Home.imaffine.png
```

Thank you.

Comment: The question was narrow enough for Mark Setchell.  His guidance led to the requested solution.  I have provided that solution in the original question.  Please remove the hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

As my original answer below doesn't seem to have worked for you, maybe you would care to try this, alternative, method. I will load your image once, save it in a `MPR` (Memory Program Register), which is a named lump of RAM, and re-use it to get each of the channels:

```
convert image.jpg -write MPR:orig +delete \
   \( MPR:orig -separate -delete 1,2 -affine <red transform>  \) \
   \( MPR:orig -separate -delete 0,2 -affine <green tranform> \) \
   \( MPR:orig -separate -delete 0,1 -affine <blue transform> \) \
   -combine result.jpg
```

**Original Answer**

No need to use `-separate`, just use the `-channel` operator to apply the transform to a selected channel:

```
convert image.png -colorspace RGB       \
    -channel R -affine <RedTransform>   \
    -channel G -affine <GreenTransform> \
    -channel B -affine <BlueTransform>  \
    result.png
```

If, after applying your distortions to the individual channels, you wish to continue applying operators to all channels, you can use `+channel` or `-channel RGB` to ensure subsequent operators apply to all channels again.

Comment: After much experimentation I found this approach did not work.  The affine transform was applied to all channels at once regardless.  So, I ended up writing a python/scipy program that did what I wanted, including applying a per-channel convolution kernel.  I may want to try again after reading the imagemagick pipeline documentation, to understand what it actually does.  I still wish for imagemagick to be the principal tool to do these things, so if anyone figures out a way, let me know.

Comment: Oh! Sorry! I will suggest a different way with IM later when I'm home.

Comment: Apologies the first answer didn't work out! t have had another try, maybe you would care to give it a shot. There may be a more concise way of doing what the new answer does, so let me know if it works as it is and if so, we can work on the cleaner version.

Comment: I'd love to use ImageMagick for a broad spectrum of transforms.  I am absolutely certain about my math.  My only uncertainty is the ability of IM to perform it for me.  I am delighted that you have an alternative you'd like me to try.

Comment: Thank you.  I put the correct answer in the question.  Direction provided by Mark Setchell was key.

Comment: Well done - your persistence has paid off! Thank you for sharing back your results with the community.